# Can my UK company order me to take a picture to show on the website?

Tags: company-culture, company-policy, company

The company is building a new website. They want to show all the employees and their experiences on it for marketing purposes.

I'm not happy at all to publish my photo and part of my resume on the website. The marketing manager said that it is my duty to be part of the website. I said absolutely not. I don't think it is my duty to show my face and my CV on a company website.

I think this is something personal and I, and me, can decide if I want to do it or not. So, the CEO said I must allow the company to publish my photo and the resume.

Can my UK company order me to take a picture to show on the website?

Comment: Do you have a reason for not wanting your photograph and CV on the website?

Comment: It is my face, why do I have to share it for a company?

Comment: My understanding of what you just wrote is "you just don't feel like it". That's important. If you had an actual reason, or a concern, then it's more likely your refusal would be considered reasonable.

Comment: I think pictures are personal. If there are not very important reasons, I don't want to show my face on the internet. Plus, once the picture is on the internet, everyone can use it for a million reasons. So, I don't want to my picture anywhere.

Comment: your CV and probably a bunch of other info about you is already on the internet (and you advertise it on your web site, which you link in your stackexchange account). If you're concerned about privacy with regards to pictures specifically (and you don't already have pictures of you on the internet somewhere, which would contradict your privacy concerns) then you have at least *something* to say about the picture (but not the CV details) being left out of the company web site. As of now it does very much sound like "I don't feel like it" though.

Comment: Sometimes people don't want photos out there because of a stalker.  That doesn't sound like your situation, however.

Comment: It's clear from your posts that you don't want to be a part of this company or anything these people are about. Just quit already and find a new job. Why be an obstinate outsider looking to be fired?

Answer (score 10):

A lot of people would have sympathy with rejecting this (including me!) and, possibly,they can't legally do it. But as usual the bigger issue is what other effect will it have. None of us can say for sure, but it's possible it impacts your career and relationship with the company. Only you can decide whether this is a hill you're willing to die on.

Of course if you've recently [rejected other company requests](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/187434/can-my-uk-company-order-me-to-join-a-social-event) the danger is the repurcusions could be much worse.

You said on your other question that you like your work. But twice now you've turned down things your employer thinks are worthwhile. I would honestly start agreeing to more things they ask or look for a new job.

Comment: Sorry, I'm asking questions because I want to know and being informed. What is the purpose of this website? Is this a website per questions and answers or for judging other people?

Comment: I'm not judging you. That's why I'm suggesting you look for a new job. You clearly dislike these things but turning them down is likely to impact your career and relationships with your boss and CEO. I just thought you might want to balance that with the fact you like your job.

Comment: I think what is being lost on the author is that as a associate director, the expectations that can be placed on them, is a great deal more than say a simply associate in the company. In my research a "associate director" is a senior position at a company.  What this means is you one of the dogs, in the [dog and pony show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog_and_pony_show), that results in money being given to the company. **The website with your profile is one of those shows.**

Comment: @EnricoR. We are not judging you here, but we are also not here to affirm your beliefs.   We are trying to give you honest feedback.  But because you have now posted 2 questions about the same company, it now gives us the opportunity to step back and look at the bigger picture - that of the relationship between you and your company.  Hence the advice of this answer.

Comment: @PeterM I'm not talking about the company I'm working with. Those are some experiences I had in past. Because I found this place, I started to ask the questions I have never had a chance before to ask.

Comment: @EnricoR. In which case, you are hiding information from us.  And that will skew the answers you receive. EG one of the answers mentions the GDPR.  If *this* question took place prior to 2016 then the GPDR is irrelevant as a response as it was only adopted in 2016.  Likewise for your other question you gave the impression that the social event was imminent, rather than a historical event.  Knowing that would have totally changed the tone of the answers you received there.

Comment: @enricoR Also you should say what actually happened Maybe you refused to go/refused to have your picture on the site and suffered no ills effects? If so you should answer you own questions: real-life-experience is valuable here.

Answer (score 0):

## Advise them that they should run this idea past legal to make sure its GDPR compliant.

Simply put, this proposal involves publishing the personal information of employees on the company's website. I'm not a lawyer, so I'm not 100% certain, but it sounds like that might not be compliant with the privacy requirements of the GDPR. As such, I would recommend that you recommend to then to delay the project while your company's legal team is consulted on the issue.